# Entire Tiles layout loaded in a tile on ajax failure

Tags: java, ajax, spring, exception, tiles

Am not sure if i had pinned a proper title, though here goes my issue:

I have a tiles layout with a header, body and footer. I use ajax request to get any data from server and populate on jsp using jquery.

On server side (Spring 3.1.2), i have used *@ExceptionHandler* provided by Spring as below:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handleAllException(Exception ex) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("error");
        model.addObject("errMsg", ex.getMessage());
        return model;
    }
```

And the tiles definition for error will be as:

```
<definition name="error"  template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/error.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
</definition>
```

So, this works good, as when any exception thrown in the application, the user will be redirected to error.jsp, where he will displayed with the error details.

NOW, comes the actual problem. In body (in one of the jsp), i have a few search fields, after entering which user could click on 'Search' to get the results and this transaction happens as an ajax request.

When there is any service exception raised during this ajax transaction, the exception is still handled by the ExceptionHandler and the response is routed to the error view. But on the UI, in the **body** part, entire template is getting loaded such that there is a 'header', 'footer' and the error page **in the body** part. if you could visualize, its like an entire screen within the body.

To avoid this, i tried response.redirect() inside the exception handler (also inside the catch{} block) to render the entire page again with error jsp. But nothing worked out...!!!

Request some help on this issue.

TIA,
Prince

Answer (score 0):

You're maybe returning the whole ModelAndView as a ResponseBody during the ajax call on the Controller part. I'm sorry but I am new here and I cannot comment on your question so I posted it as an answer

Comment: Yes Jorrin, i do. But the issue here is because of the ajax request, coz of which the response is getting commited as an ajax response. In normal cases, the view will get resolved by the view resolver and the page will get redirected to the error apge as desired.